# Make default value in field equal to the database name in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

***Updated***

I would like to create a database table that contains the database name for every record that gets created and concatenates it with an auto-incrementing number. Please see below what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST_1234_5678
GO
USE TEST_1234_5678
GO

CREATE TABLE TBL_ANALYSIS
(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT DB_NAME()
 DESIRED_ID VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT DATABASE_NAME + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)
);
```

I am unable to assign DESIRED_ID.

Comment: It's working for me: `INSERT INTO TBL_ANALYSIS DEFAULT VALUES;`

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: DB_NAME() requieres ALTER ANY DATABASE permisions

Comment: why do not just use the database name default('TEST_1234_5678')?

Comment: The default constraint should work unless you've revoked or denied `VIEW ANY DATABASE` from public (assigned by default). However, you should define the column data type as `sysname` to avoid truncation errors if the database name changes.

Comment: No repro from me either. Did you encounter some *other* problem perhaps? Post the *actual* query and *verbatim* error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, running `CREATE DATABASE` does not switch you to that context.  If, for instance, I'm currently connected to `My_DB` and run your `CREATE DATABASE` command, the DB might be created, but I'll still be working on `My_DB`.

I only point that out because your question doesn't show that you're switching DB context, and that might be relevant, depending on how your server is set up.

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST_1234_5678
GO

USE TEST_1234_5678
GO

CREATE TABLE TBL_ANALYSIS
(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT DB_NAME()
)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL_ANALYSIS DEFAULT VALUES
GO
```

Depending on the error you're getting, this could be a number of different things.  Assuming that you're in the right context and connected as a user with permissions, the error message you're getting could be extremely important to solve the issue.  I would recommend ensuring that you're switching contexts, and if it still isn't working for you you might considering editing your question and posting the actual error message.

> **EDIT:** After getting some more information from you, I understand that the issue is in trying to create a column with a default value
>   based on other columns in the table.  This isn't something that is
>   supported in SQL Server, but you can use a computed column to get the
>   same information.  Since this isn't a complex operation, you could do
>   something as simple as this:
>
> ```
> CREATE DATABASE TEST_1234_5678
> GO
>
> USE TEST_1234_5678
> GO
>
> CREATE TABLE TBL_ANALYSIS
> (
>    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
>   ,DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT DB_NAME()
>   ,DESIRED_ID AS DATABASE_NAME + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(14))     
> )
> GO
>
> INSERT INTO TBL_ANALYSIS DEFAULT VALUES
> GO
>
> SELECT * FROM TBL_ANALYSIS
> GO
> ```

Comment: I looked through what I wrote and realized that the error was coming from the concatenation part. Here's an
    CREATE TABLE TBL_ANALYSIS
    (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT DB_NAME(),
    DESIRED_ID VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT DATABASE_NAME + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)
    );
This gives me the following error: 
    The name "ID" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Okay, so essentially your question is misleading people.  The problem isn't that you get an error regarding the use of DB_NAME(), but rather the concatenated default value that you're trying to insert into DESIRED_ID.

Comment: @Xavier Updated my answer to be more relevant to your actual question.  I would highly recommend you append/edit your original question so that the actual problem is reflected - everyone thinks that your problem is inserting DB_NAME() as a default value.

Comment: Your edited response answered my question. The misleading part was unintentional; I wrote the question while on my cell phone rather than on the PC that had my query and apparently wrote what I remembered. I've revised the question for the sake of future reference & apologize to all for the confusion.